# how to track google referral traffic

Tags: php, referrer, http-referer

I want track google referral traffic.i used below code but i searched on google.com then in referral path shows site home page referral not showing google.com as referrer.

please check.

Comment: I do not see "`google`" anywhere in your code.How do you intend to track Google if you are not looking for it?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I'm guessing the OP is talking about the $_SERVER referer  I'm guessing they just print that. Problem still is that this header is unreliable. Most modern browsers allow to go to page without submitting the header all together. And some sites before transferring mangle the header value.

Comment: instead of google.com i click on abc.com and then click on my website link present on abc.com then m getting correct referral i.e abc.com but same thing not happened with google.com

Answer (score 0):

**15.1.3 Encoding Sensitive Information in URI's**

Because the source of a link might be private information or might reveal an otherwise private information source, it is strongly recommended that the user be able to select whether or not the Referer field is sent. For example, a browser client could have a toggle switch for browsing openly/anonymously, which would respectively enable/disable the sending of Referer and From information.

**Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure) HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure protocol.**

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3